# Job offer was rescinded due to security clearance?

Tags: security

My husband received a conditional offer for a job that required security clearance. After they investigated him the report has "No Determination Status. Therefore the job offer was rescinded. We are holding off applying to other goverment jobs, untill we figure out what's up on his records. Can anyone point us
where to or what to do on this situation

Comment: What country was this?

Comment: Could you elaborate on what the report said? After a brief Google search, "no determination status" does not seem to be a widely used expression. What else did the report say? Which organization did it come from?

Comment: Was this a job that required an existing security clearance or was it a job that required the ability to obtain and maintain a security clearance? Some positions require you to already have a certain level that can be checked and transferred in, while others will sponsor you for a new clearance. Unfortunately, individuals don't have much insight into the process unless they go through a company's security officer.

Answer (score 5):

I'm no expert,  but from what I can see "No Determination Status" won't be about what's in the file,  but rather that they didn't find enough information to determine the clearance.   So likely they didn't get enough info from any references/employers to make a decision.

Answer (score 1):

Page 8 of this report: http://fas.org/sgp/othergov/intel/clear-2013.pdf contains some reasons why people were denied/had their clearance revoked.

there is also this article:
http://news.clearancejobs.com/2009/11/14/rebutting-and-appealing-security-clearance-denials/

I think we need more details than you probably want to provide to offer better insight.